flex wrap не переносит изображения
введите сюда код
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/leeee.css">
    <script src="index.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="flex flex-wrap mx-2">
        <div class="sm:w-1/2 md:w-1/3 lg:w-1/5 px-2 mb-4">
            <img class="min-w-40" src="сылка на фото очень длинная" alt="Photo 1">
        </div>
        <div class="sm:w-1/2 md:w-1/3 lg:w-1/5 px-2 mb-4">
            <img class="min-w-40" src="сылка на фото очень длинная" alt="Photo 2">
        </div>
        <div class="sm:w-1/2 md:w-1/3 lg:w-1/5 px-2 mb-4">
            <img class="min-w-40" src="сылка на фото очень длинная" alt="Photo 3">
        </div>
        <div class="sm:w-1/2 md:w-1/3 lg:w-1/5 px-2 mb-4">
            <img class="min-w-40" src="сылка на фото очень длинная" alt="Photo 4">
        </div>
        <div class="sm:w-1/2 md:w-1/3 lg:w-1/5 px-2 mb-4">
            <img class="min-w-40" src="сылка на фото очень длинная" alt="Photo 5">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Пробывал устанавливать минимальную ширину для изображений , дивов в которых изображения , главного дива , еще заметил что по дефолту тейлвинд ставил max width 100% для всех изображений и видео, когда я отключил max width 100% изображения не уменьшались и не переносились , а просто уходили за рамки браузерного окна.
